# How to optimize xamarin android app size?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I try to understand why my app has a size of more than 250Mb which is huge.

When I analyse the APK, I see that all the versions of Achitecture are embedded inside.

Which  version should I choose because I can't embed the 4:

[image]

Also: I have this setup may I optimize it? I need AOT and startup tracing to improve performance at stratup.

[image]

Comment: "Which version should I choose" - which versions do your users need?

Comment: I have seen that X86 is mainly for emulators. So I will remove them. And I have seen I can generate an APK foreach versions. Which shrinks my app size. But Google app store accepts multiple versions?

Comment: you can refer to thease links https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/shrinking-android-app-size/

Comment: https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/reducing-the-app-size-in-xamarin-deep-dive-7ddc9cb12688